# Odoo 17 Qweb Report - How to get a field from another model

Tags: odoo, qweb

Hope everyone is fine.

I'm working on reports from Odoo 17 with the studio customisation.

I'm trying to improve my `report_picking` template by adding the `product_code` from the `product.supplierinfo` depending on the serial number. The idea is to get, on the same line, the description of the product, the serial number and the supplier code.

As for everything else it's pretty easy, I can't find a way to add this `product_code` field and the documentation is pretty terrible.

Can someone give me a hand in this ?
Thanks !

I'm searching into every accessible field from qweb, checking into class and looking throught the web & the doc.